# Invalid table alias or column reference 'SYNTHJOIN_xxxxx'

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery, teradata, alias

would appreciate a few extra set of eyes;
I cannot figure out for the life of me why this query won't work, I'm converting Teradata SQL scripts to Hive.

```
        Select a.some_id FROM app_table_dc.seds_thingy_mapping_seds_vdata   e
         LEFT JOIN app_table_dc.assets a
            ON e.eng_serial_number = a.serial_number
            AND a.asset_type_id = 2
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT vdata_thingy_id
                                        , thingy_date InductDate
                                    FROM app_table_dc.seds_thingy_mapping_seds_vdata
                                    WHERE thingy_type = 'EI') ei

   ON ei.vdata_thingy_id = e.vdata_thingy_id
     JOIN app_table_dc.engine_type_asset_models am
        ON a.asset_model_id = am.asset_model_id
     JOIN app_table_dc.engine_type egt
        ON am.engine_type_id = egt.engine_type_id
```

The last two lines do NOT work; when I take them out, it'll run...However with them included, I end up with the error logs to show :

> Error Code: 10004, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS,
>   infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error
>   while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]:
>   Line 1:4915 Invalid table alias or column reference
>   'SYNTHJOIN_110d3abf': (possible column names are: blahblahblah)

I made sure the table names being referred to had the correct nomenclature/names, as well as the columns being referred to. I'm at my wits end.

Thank you for any insight in advance!

Comment: As per my understanding there is no issue with your query, would need some more details - last 2 lines refer to table (app_table_dc.engine_type) ,  are you able to query this table without any errors and is this an external/internal table with/without partitions

Comment: Hi, and yes, I can query this table with no issues, it is a very small associative entity table, with just 10 or so rows.  It isn't transactional, I believe it's an internal table as should be the linking/joined table, No Partitions.  Though theres 34 unique ids on the first table and like I said just 10 unique ids to map on the second.. Though I highly doubt that is the issue.

Comment: Can you please check that column `engine_type_id ` do exists in both table and with the same type?

Comment: Yes, engine_type_id exists in both tables as BIGINT.  Strange right?

Answer (score 0):

--the code is right

--since I see this error :(possible column names are: blahblahblah)

Can you check if asset_model_id  and engine_type_id  are present in both the tables((a,am),(am,egt)) you are joining with.

May be the naming is different due to which it is throwing an error.

Comment: engine_type_id exists in both tables as well as asset_model_id in ((am,egt) ,(a,am))...   but ... I think perhaps the column names are changing because of the alias prefix...   perhaps that's what is throwing it off?   some kind of misalignment? though it doesn't explain how the first two joins work...I have no idea

Comment: Select a.some_id 
 FROM 
  app_table_dc.seds_thingy_mapping_seds_vdata e
    LEFT JOIN
  app_table_dc.assets a
    ON e.eng_serial_number = a.serial_number
    AND a.asset_type_id = 2
    LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT vdata_thingy_id , thingy_date InductDate
            FROM 
   app_table_dc.seds_thingy_mapping_seds_vdata
         WHERE thingy_type = 'EI'
  ) ei

 ON ei.vdata_thingy_id = e.vdata_thingy_id
    JOIN app_table_dc.engine_type_asset_models am
    ON a.asset_model_id = am.asset_model_id
    JOIN app_table_dc.engine_type egt
    ON am.engine_type_id = egt.engine_type_id

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Returns the same error "Invalid table alias or column reference 'SYNTHJOIN_3812a350', possible column names are: mapping_seq, vdata_thingy_id, seds_thingy_ref, thingy_type, eng_serial_number, thingy_date, new_vdata_thingy_id, etl_src_system  I think I'm going to have to use CTE or smaller tables somehow to break this down... :(

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/150153/semanticexception-error-10004-line-50-invalid-tabl.html , set hive.server2.enable.doAs=true

Answer (score 0):

This was the only recourse that worked:

```
    with somealias as (select * from app_table_dc.engine_type)
                Select a.some_id 
            FROM app_table_dc.seds_thingy_mapping_seds_vdata e 
            LEFT JOIN app_table_dc.assets a ON e.eng_serial_number = a.serial_number AND a.asset_type_id = 2 
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT vdata_thingy_id , thingy_date InductDate FROM app_table_dc.seds_thingy_mapping_seds_vdata WHERE thingy_type = 'EI' ) ei 
            ON ei.vdata_thingy_id = e.vdata_thingy_id 
            JOIN app_table_dc.engine_type_asset_models am ON a.asset_model_id = am.asset_model_id 
    JOIN somealias egt 
ON am.engine_type_id = egt.engine_type_id
```